# Something is consuming my Ctrl+C

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I inherited this Computer and it was originally set up with emacs as the default keyboard layout. I switched it to Windows, but now I cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for anything.

In a terminal it does nothing (does not halt the execution), and in text editing it does not copy (even though if I write click the copy hint id <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

I'm not sure what is consuming my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or how to fix it.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> work exactly as expected.

Comment: Check under Settings>>Keyboard>>Shortcuts>>Custom Shortcuts. If there aren't any set, check the other fields to see if `ctrl+c` is set for any of them.

Comment: where did you change this setting? all I can find for the default keyboard layout in ubuntu is for languages like US or GB and nothing for emacs or windows.

Comment: Also, what version and distro of ubuntu are you using (i.e. 14.04, 12.04 etc and  Ubuntu, Kubuntu etc. )?

Comment: +chaskes Windows/PC keyboard layout, not MS windows. I didn't even know there was an Emacs keyboard layout, but I do know that if you're in North America you'll probably be using the PC(/Windows) keyboard layout. I know I had to change the keyboard layout to this when I set up my Raspberry Pi, as it defaults to the UK keyboard layout.

Comment: Whenever you inherit a computer, you don't know (factually) what was on it before hand nor do you know what it was used for. The beautiful thing about a computer is ownership - make it your own. This doesn't answer your question but my suggestion is that you wipe and re-install the OS. Why? It's your computer. You're now accountable for what is on it and you might as well make it your own.

Comment: Just so you know, it's @username not +username to ping someone. Please edit your question to specify the exact keyboard layout you are using (rather than just saying windows). :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. While the computer was still using the emacs shortcuts, I tried to add a custom <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut - it hadn't worked. When I switched away from emacs shortcuts, my non-operational custom <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut was still in place! How annoying of me!

Thank you @Zacharee1, @mchid, @Hitechcomputergeek, @KGIII, and @chaskes!